# How to fix this C++ Memory Management?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I want to build a Memory Management to avoid memory leak but my code has an error that I have no idea how to fix, and how to fix the error in the code?

There: `EMC_DELETE cls2; // <-- error: expected a ';'`

This code is referenced from a GLSL parser (https://github.com/graphitemaster/glsl-parser/blob/main/ast.h).

```
// A helper function to help other to reproduce the same example.
std::string pathFolderOrFileName(const std::string &path) {
    return path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);
}

template <typename T>
static inline void _destroy(void *self) {
    ((T*)self)->~T();
    free(self);
}
struct Memory {
    // Memory Management that's referenced from "emc-language > lexer-parser > ast.h".
    Memory() : data(0), dtor(0) { }
    template <typename T>
    Memory(T *data, const char *file, int line) :
        data((void*)data),
        dtor(&_destroy<T>),
        file(file),
        line(line)
    {}
    
    void *data;
    void (*dtor)(void*);
    const char *file;
    int line;
    
    void destroy() {
        dtor(data);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    void *operator new(size_t size, std::vector<Memory> *collector, const char *file, int line) throw() {
        void *data = malloc(size);
        if (data) {
            collector->push_back(Memory((T *)data, file, line));
        }
        return data;
    }

    void operator delete(void *data, std::vector<Memory> *collector) {
        auto &vec = *collector;
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            if (vec[i].data == data) {
                vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
                free(data);
                return;
            }
        }
        assert(0);
    }
};

// Note: Never use the default 'operator new & delete' because they can cause memory leak.
#define EMC_NEW new(&g_memory, __FILE__, __LINE__) // Use this instead of using the default 'operator new'.
#define EMC_DELETE delete(&g_memory)               // Use this instead of using default 'operator delete'.

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyBaseClass {
public:
    int base_x, base_y;
};

class MyClass : public Node<MyClass> {
public:
    int x, y;

    MyClass() {
    }
    ~MyClass() {
    }
};

std::vector<Memory> g_memory;

int main() {
    MyClass *cls0 = EMC_NEW MyClass();
    MyClass *cls1 = EMC_NEW MyClass();
    MyClass *cls2 = EMC_NEW MyClass();
    EMC_DELETE cls2; // <-- error: expected a ';'

    for (int i = 0; i < g_memory.size(); i++) {
        auto &it = g_memory[i];
        printf("%d: (file \"%s\", line %d)\n", i, pathFolderOrFileName(it.file).c_str(), it.line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
0: (file "test_draft.cpp", line 79)
1: (file "test_draft.cpp", line 80)
2: (file "test_draft.cpp", line 81) this line must be removed because cls2 must be deleted.
```

Comment: Having to wade through too many unreported errors to get to the one you are asking about. Could we get a [mre]?

Comment: The `new(&g_memory, __FILE__, __LINE__)` is referenced from the link I gave, and as you can see on the output, it works. And I'm guessing how to do the same thing with `delete`? But I don't know how. I tried to add a member variable `_collectors` in `Memory` but it causes this `invalid use of member 'Node<T>::_collector' in static member function` because inside an operator new / delete function.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "placement delete" - you cannot write `delete(&g_memory) cls2`

Comment: @UnholySheep, I know it's an error but is there an alternative method to fix my problem?

Comment: @mandaxyz you delete whatever `new` operator returns, not the memory the object was allocated in

Comment: I mean, I tried to add a member variable `_collector` in `struct Node` but it causes an error. I wanted to remove the extra argument with the operator delete.

Comment: @The Dreams Wind, if I just use the default `operator delete` with the `cls2` then the function `void operator delete(void *data, std::vector<Memory> *collector) ` is not called and it's not removed from the collector.

Comment: https://ideone.com/mGprj7 `new` and `delete` are actually static operators and not called on any instance. That means the variable that needs to be accessed within them also needs to be static.

Comment: @Brandon, I tired to turn `_collector` into `g_collector` as global variable (synonym of static) and the error is gone, but my big question is "Is it thread safe?", will it crash for advanced programming with multi thread? I'm not sure.

Comment: I cannot believe that I can fix the problem when I was on bed, this is the solution:
`#define EMC_DELETE(x) (x)->operator delete((x), &g_memory)` where `g_memory` can be replaced with any group memory.